# WorksheetFunction.Small ERROR?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ArrTest() As Variant
Dim ArrSmall() As Variant
Dim ArrTemp() As Variant

Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sub test()

ReDim ArrTest(10, 2)
ReDim ArrSmall(10, 2)
ReDim ArrTemp(10, 1)


ArrTest = Range("A1:B10")
For k = 1 To 2
For i = 1 To 10

ArrTemp(i, 1) = ArrTest(i, k)
ArrSmall(i, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTemp, i)

Cells(i, k + 10) = ArrSmall(i, k)
Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

`Range("A1:B10")` is an arbitrary range of numbers which should be ordered from small to big according to the WorksheetFunction.Small. With a single column this works perfectly fine. However, when applied as such (with a loop) the function copies values from the original range and the output is wrong.

Please try for yourself in an Excel sheet and tell me what I'm doing wrong or the function is wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have it working with `Application.Index` which works in this particular example. See:

```
Sub test()

ReDim ArrTest(10, 2)
ReDim ArrSmall(10, 2)
ReDim ArrTemp(10, 1)


ArrTest = Range("A1:B10")
For k = 1 To 2
For i = 1 To 10

ArrTemp = Application.Index(ArrTest, 0, k)

'ArrTemp(i, 1) = ArrTest(i, 1)
ArrSmall(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTemp, i)

Cells(i, k + 10) = ArrSmall(i, 1)

Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

Which works fine. But when I apply the exact same logic to my original code it gives me the 1004 error: unable to get Small property. I have no clue.

Comment: Are the values unique? for example if they are all 1's and there are 20 entries, small(a1:b10,20) will still work, but will return 1, so this maybe affecting the return?

Comment: Yes, the values are unique.

Comment: if `k` and `i` is `1` (first loop) what do you think `ArrSmall(i, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTemp, i)` will do? there is only one value in `ArrTemp` (at `(1, 1)` and `(2, 1)` to `(10, 1)` is not definded). also all later loops will mess up this way... and secondly no `Base 1` is given => `ReDim ArrTemp(10, 1)` will be `ReDim ArrTemp(0 To 10, 0 To 1)` and not `ReDim ArrTemp(1 To 10, 1 To 1)` as you may think ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel Copy paste the second code snippet into your VBA. Add some values in the specified range (or even make it bigger) and hit F5... This WorksheetFunction.Small is driving me crazy because it produces the correct result! Although in my original code it produces an error.

Comment: For some reason I can make it SMALL three columns but on 4 columns it reverts back to the standard error. Is there a limit??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to leave your code as much as it was (first example) works perfect:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ArrTest() As Variant
Dim ArrSmall() As Variant
Dim ArrTemp() As Variant

Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sub test()

ReDim ArrTest(10, 2) '*
ReDim ArrSmall(10, 2)
ReDim ArrTemp(10, 1)


ArrTest = Range("A1:B10")
For k = 1 To 2
  For i = 1 To 10
    ArrTemp(i, 1) = ArrTest(i, k)
  Next i

  For i = 1 To 10
    ArrSmall(i, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTemp, i)
    Cells(i, k + 10) = ArrSmall(i, k)
  Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

No errors or whatever at all... 
the `'*` just is not used at all `ArrTest = Range("A1:B10")` will set automatically all ranges... still the ranges would be to big for the other ranges...

I get exactly the same output like in your second example...

**EDIT:**
If you want to sort the full range (not every column itself) then you need something like:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ArrTest() As Variant
Dim ArrSmall() As Variant
Dim ArrTemp() As Variant

Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sub test()

ReDim ArrTest(10, 2)
ReDim ArrSmall(10, 2)
ReDim ArrTemp(10, 1)

ArrTest = Range("A1:B10")
For k = 1 To UBound(ArrTest, 2)
  For i = 1 To UBound(ArrTest)
    ArrSmall(i, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTest, i + ((k - 1) * UBound(ArrTest)))
    Cells(i, k + 10) = ArrSmall(i, k)
  Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

Still I beleave the first code should do what you desire ;)

Comment: This works. I honestly thought I already tried this double loop but I seem to have messed something up. It also works on my original code! Thanks a bunch! This was such a hell...

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the [ReDim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) is creating too many elements in the arrays. Try using the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) **after** setting the worksheet range values into the first variant array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ArrTest() As Variant, ArrSmall() As Variant, ArrTemp() As Variant
    Dim k As Long, i As Long

    ReDim ArrTest(10, 2)   '<~~ unnecessary if writing values from the worksheet
    Debug.Print LBound(ArrTest, 1) & ":" & UBound(ArrTest, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(ArrTest, 2) & ":" & UBound(ArrTest, 2)
    '^^ this results in 0:10, 0:2. Not 1:10, 1:2

    ArrTest = Range("A1:B10").Value2  '<~~ make sure you are putting values in
    Debug.Print LBound(ArrTest, 1) & ":" & UBound(ArrTest, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(ArrTest, 2) & ":" & UBound(ArrTest, 2)
    '^^ this results in 1:10, 1:2.

    ReDim ArrSmall(LBound(ArrTest, 1) To UBound(ArrTest, 1), _
                   LBound(ArrTest, 2) To UBound(ArrTest, 2))
    ReDim ArrTemp(LBound(ArrTest, 1) To UBound(ArrTest, 1), 1 To 1)


    For k = LBound(ArrTest, 2) To UBound(ArrTest, 2)
        For i = LBound(ArrTest, 1) To UBound(ArrTest, 1)

        ArrTemp(i, 1) = ArrTest(i, k)
        ArrSmall(i, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTemp, i)

        Cells(i, k + 10) = ArrSmall(i, k)
        Next i
    Next k

End Sub
```

[image: lbound_ubound_small]

Comment: Sorry @DirkReichel - I thought I had reverted the [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685)s that I used to populate A1:B10 to their values before I took the screenshot but I guess I didn't. I've redone the image with a rerun of the procedure. I wasn't paying close attention to the results as I had no idea what it was intended to accomplish. I was aiming more for the working code.

Comment: OK... was just confused how this could happen at all :P

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you write the code.

```
Sub test()

With Range("A1:B10")
    For Each Column In .Columns
        x = x + 1
        For i = 1 To Column.Cells.Count
            Cells(i, 10 + x).Value = Application.Small(Column, i)
        Next i
    Next Column
End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

> Although this would work with Range my goal is to extract the columns
>   from an array without having to return to a Sheet. I think this is
>   limited somehow

Adding Array approach too..

```
Sub test()
Dim vArr As Variant, varrTemp As Variant

vArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:B10").Value)

For i = LBound(vArr, 1) To UBound(vArr, 1)
    varrTemp = Application.Index(Application.Transpose(vArr), , i)
    For x = LBound(varrTemp) To UBound(varrTemp)
        Cells(x, 10 + i).Value = Application.Small(varrTemp, x)
    Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Although this would work with Range my goal is to extract the columns from an array without having to return to a Sheet. I think this is limited somehow.

Comment: No. Refer my Answer post to know how to convert it as array (updated the post with array method) and retrieve the result using Small() function.